# SocketException: Connection reset while FTP upload

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server.
This is my code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
try {
    List<PoiCmsRule> appPois = getAllRules();
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(backupFile)) {
        new Gson().toJson(backupData, writer);
    }
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(backupFile)) {
        ftpClient.connect(host);
        ftpClient.login(login, password);
        ftpClient.storeFile("backup.json", fis);
        ftpClient.logout();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    try {
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly fine when I run this on localhost. But when I run in on server I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
```

I think it indicates I might have some problems with the firewall or proxy.

This is a Spring Boot app run on the Ubuntu server with Nginx as a proxy.

How can I find what is causing this exception?

---

Logs from a successful connection with command-line `ftp` in passive mode:

```
ubuntu@ip-server:~$ ftp -p -d my_host
Connected to my_host
220 FTP-Server
ftp: setsockopt: Bad file descriptor
Name (my_host): username
---> USER username
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
---> PASS XXXX
230 Login successful.
---> SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied
---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (153,92,207,128,127,65)
---> LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
// file list
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Commons Net `FTPClient` defaults to the FTP *active* mode. The active mode hardly ever works these days due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs (for details, see my article on [FTP active/passive connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes)).

To switch `FTPClient` to the *passive* mode, call [`FTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode()) somewhere *after* `FTPClient.connect`:

```
ftpClient.connect(host);
ftpClient.login(login, password);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```